# Unassisted remote APK install and launch

Tags: android, apk, mdm

I've been told that there is a way to create an apk that can be installed on an android device and allow a remote server to install and launch a new apk remotely without any user input.

This would be done on a closed network of android devices, this is not intended to be a published app in the store.  I've not been able to find any information on this.

Has this been done before?  This would be differnt from installing an apk that checks for content updates, in my experience even with an MDM you can not push, install, and launch a new APK without a user interaction on the remote device.

Comment: Note to others encountering this question: the OP is open to solutions involving rooted devices or custom ROMs.

Comment: you must have "android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" and system signature. to install package, you have to invoke "android.content.pm.IPackageManager.installPackage(...)".

Comment: you can do it if you have root - i have.  it's a long story to give all the details, but the magic is launching the shell command `pm` via `su` to install the apk.  the rest is normal android stuff

Comment: ahhh thank you Joe and SteelBytes.. I'll give those a try!  are you posting your app updates to a server and the remote device 'checks' for updates periodically?

Answer (score 1):

You can upload the app to Google Play, as an alpha or beta version.
Then, you can enroll in the alpha or beta on the Android device.
Make sure auto-updating is on in Google Play, and within a few hours after the update is submitted, the update should be pushed to the devices in the alpha/beta program.

Comment: Thank you,  I've just looked at releasing in the play store as an alpha or beta version however it looks like a user is required to initiate a download using a link.. then I'm assuming would be required to launch the app as well.  I'm curious if there is a way to push, download, and launch an app remotely all with out user interaction on the remote device.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments a solution to remote apk install is to root your device(s) or build a custom ROM and then creating a system application with the `android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES` permission. This may be better for your use case than going through Google Play because Play requires the device to have a Google account signed in and auto-updates enabled by the user.

The issue with rooting devices or creating a custom ROM is the amount of maintenance and setup for each device. You also have the risk of introducing security flaws to your devices and application.

You can also look at MDM solutions to achieve the same result:

[Samsung Knox](https://www.samsungknox.com/en/article/manage-apps) lets you upload an app to their service and "the app automatically installs on users' devices inside the Knox container".

[AirWatch](http://www.air-watch.com/solutions/mobile-device-management/) lets you "Deploy public, internal or bulk-purchased apps to devices automatically or to an enterprise app catalog for on-demand install".

[Mason](https://bymason.com/) lets you upload your apk and push it to your devices instantly. You also get additional controls like making your app the direct boot package, locking your app in kiosk mode, or preventing the user from getting into Settings. If this sounds it would fit your use case, feel free to reach out to me: `trevor @ bymason.com`

**DISCLAIMER: I work for Mason**